# In WPF based desktop app touch drag and drop is working on window 7 but not on Window 8

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0

I am developing WPF based desktop application. I have Implemented Touch drag and drop functionality. Its working perfectly on Window 7 . But on window 8 its not working.
In window 8 , when i am doing double tap on any file(image , mp3 or video) and then drag the content , then its working fine.

But this behaviour is wrong, I want the normal behaviour as working on window 7 (Simple touch and drag  the file)

Please help me.

Comment: This might have to do w/ the OS settings of Windows 8. Look at "Pen and Touch" settings